# Search for file using VBA in MSWord

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need my Macro to search for a specific file without knowing the full file path, then to either open the file or return the file path. I´ve tried searching online but most of the answers don't seem to work for me. The closest I got was a function to search for folders, but I wasn't able to modify it to search for files
(courtesy of https://vbahowto.com/how-to-search-for-a-folder-in-vba/).

```
Sub Main()

Dim fsoFileSystem As Object
Dim strMainFolder As String
Dim strLookFor As String

strLookFor = "working"
strMainFolder = "C:\a"

Set fsoFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
DoSubFolders fsoFileSystem.GetFolder(strMainFolder), strLookFor

'if the code didn't find the folder, you will get this message.
Msgbox "'" & strLookFor & "' is not found so go ahead and create it.", vbInformation

End Sub

Sub DoSubFolders(Folder, strLookFor)
Dim objSubFolder As Object

For Each objSubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
    
    Debug.Print "*****************************************"
    Debug.Print "SubFolder= " & objSubFolder.Name
    Debug.Print "*****************************************"
    
    If objSubFolder.Name = strLookFor Then
        MsgBox "You already have a folder called '" & strLookFor & "' at '" & objSubFolder.Path & "' . Don't add it again.", vbInformation
        
        'Exit the search
        End
        
    End If
    
    DoSubFolders objSubFolder, strLookFor
Next
Dim objFile As Object
For Each objFile In Folder.Files
    ' Operate on each file
    Debug.Print "FileName= " & objFile.Name
    
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Will there be exactly one file containing "working" or could there be several files containing "working" in on of the subfolders of c:\a

Comment: Is there a specific file format? or any type of file is fine as long as it matches `strLookFor`?

Comment: Ike: Yes, the file name will be unique

Comment: @RaymondWu: The file type will be either .png or .txt. But the names will be unique so any type of file should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a non-recursive version:

```
Sub FindFile()
    'Define the file name and main folder
    Const strLookFor As String = "working"
    Const strMainFolder As String = "C:\a"
    
    Dim targetFilePath As String
        
    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim folderColl As Collection
    Set folderColl = New Collection
    folderColl.Add strMainFolder
    
    Do While folderColl.Count <> 0 And targetFilePath = vbNullString
        Dim searchFolder As Object
        Set searchFolder = FSO.GetFolder(folderColl(1))
        
        'Look for the file
        Dim loopFile As Object
        For Each loopFile In searchFolder.Files
            If FSO.GetBaseName(loopFile.Name) = strLookFor Then
                targetFilePath = loopFile.Path
                Exit For
            End If
        Next loopFile
        
        'Add current folder's subfolders into the collection
        Dim loopFolder As Object
        For Each loopFolder In searchFolder.SubFolders
            folderColl.Add loopFolder.Path
        Next loopFolder
        
        folderColl.Remove 1
    Loop
    
    'Check if the file is found
    If targetFilePath <> vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "File found." & vbNewLine & targetFilePath
    Else
        MsgBox "File not found."
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edit - Function version**:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim strLookFor As String
    Dim strMainFolder As String
    
    strLookFor = "working"
    strMainFolder = "D:\Temp\FindFile"
    
    Dim targetFilePath As String
    targetFilePath = FindFile(strMainFolder, strLookFor)
    
    'Check if the file is found
    If targetFilePath <> vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "File found." & vbNewLine & targetFilePath
    Else
        MsgBox "File not found."
    End If
End Sub

Function FindFile(strMainFolder As String, strLookFor As String) As String
    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim folderColl As Collection
    Set folderColl = New Collection
    folderColl.Add strMainFolder
    
    Do While folderColl.Count <> 0
        Dim searchFolder As Object
        Set searchFolder = FSO.GetFolder(folderColl(1))
        
        'Look for the file
        Dim loopFile As Object
        For Each loopFile In searchFolder.Files
            If FSO.GetBaseName(loopFile.Name) = strLookFor Then
                FindFile = loopFile.Path
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next loopFile
        
        'Add current folder's subfolders into the collection
        Dim loopFolder As Object
        For Each loopFolder In searchFolder.SubFolders
            folderColl.Add loopFolder.Path
        Next loopFolder
        
        folderColl.Remove 1
    Loop
End Function
```

Comment: Feel free to ask if you don't understand how the code works, some consideration for you - If you want the search to be case-insensitive then change `If FSO.GetBaseName(loopFile.Name) = strLookFor Then` to `If UCase(FSO.GetBaseName(loopFile.Name)) = UCase(strLookFor) Then` @RedVortex

Comment: Thanks. Well if you're offering, I don't really understand the usage of the collection data type. Also, I converted the sub to a function. Now I gett "Error 76, Path not found" on line `Set searchFolder = FSO.GetFolder(folderColl(1))`

Comment: Collection is like array except that you don't have to `ReDim` the dimension beforehand, you can keep adding things into the collection and it will hold the variable in sequence so the idea the `While` loop will continue as long the collection has something in it and then set `searchFolder` to the first item in the collection (which is the folder path). We then remove the first item from the collection using `folderColl.Remove 1` so now the item that was in the 2nd index moves up to 1st. [Collection article](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-collections/)

Comment: @RedVortex Can you `Debug.Print foldercoll(1)` and see if it's a valid folder path? Is the path on a network drive or local drive?

Comment: `Debug.Print foldercoll(1)` returns only the file name, `strLookFor`. The path is on a network drive. I assume that it doesn't work because when I wrote the sub as a function, I did not declare `strLookFor` and `strMainFolder` as a `Const`, but have them only as function arguments.

Comment: `FolderColl` should return the folder path.. not file name, so you require a function instead? @RedVortex

Comment: I need to search for around 8-12 files in the macro, so yes, a function should be easier. @Raymond Wu

Comment: @RedVortex See my edited code at the bottom of the answer, tweak it as per your requirement or if you like me to help you with that, provide me more details (is the main folder to search in constant? how are you getting the file name of these 8-12 files? are they in an array already?)

Comment: @RedVortex I made some edit in the function that you might have missed it (removed `And targetFilePath = vbNullString` in `Do While folderColl.Count <> 0 And targetFilePath = vbNullString`

Comment: Works. Thank you so much. You have no idea how much this helps me. I would feel bad taking any more of your time, so i think i will manage.